# scrollTop does not work well inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html file created with cloudconvert.com that I wrapped with java script to highlight text inside it and scroll to first highlight using JQuery scrollTop() function.  See example:

```js
function doSearch2(text,color) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();

        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, color);
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, color);
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }

        var sel2 = document.getSelection();
        var seltop = $(sel2.anchorNode.parentElement).offset().top;
        var doccurrenttop = $('#page-container').scrollTop();
        var scrollto = doccurrenttop + seltop - 70; // spce of 70px
        if (scrollto < 0) { scrollto = 0; }
        $('#page-container').scrollTop(scrollto);
}

doSearch2("Cross","yellow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3c3vx862/

I try to insert doSearch2() function into the head of the html file and load it on iframe inside new html document. Then I call doSearch2() from button on the outer document.

The scrollTop works fine, except on some cases (like scrolling to the bottom of the document and other random locations). When I debug it I find that sel2 (= document.getSelection()) is zero.

Any Ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesnt work probably for all that generated script and html you have there but you can take a look at this jsfiddle I made for you here.

Add this to your html page:

```
<a href="#0" class="cd-top">Top</a>
```

Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link is shown
var offset = 300,
    //browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "back to top" link opacity is reduced
    offset_opacity = 1200,
    //duration of the top scrolling animation (in ms)
    scroll_top_duration = 700,
    //grab the "back to top" link
    $back_to_top = $('.cd-top');

//hide or show the "back to top" link
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('cd-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('cd-is-visible cd-fade-out');
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
        $back_to_top.addClass('cd-fade-out');
    }
});

//smooth scroll to top
$back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0 ,
        }, scroll_top_duration
    );
});

});
```

CSS

```
.cd-top {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 100px;
 right: 10px;
 z-index: 10;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 /* image replacement properties */
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 background: rgba(232, 98, 86, 0.8) url(../img/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat   center 50%;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
 -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
 transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s; 
 }
.cd-top.cd-is-visible, .cd-top.cd-fade-out, .no-touch .cd-top:hover {
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s; 
}
.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
/* the button becomes visible */
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}
.cd-top.cd-fade-out {
/* if the user keeps scrolling down, the button is out of focus and becomes    less visible */
opacity: .5;
}
.no-touch .cd-top:hover {
 background-color: #e86256;
 opacity: 1;
 }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .cd-top {
 right: 20px;
 bottom: 20px;
  }
 }
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.cd-top {
height: 60px;
width: 60px;
right: 30px;
bottom: 30px;
 }
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmaqwceu/)

Comment: Thank you Robert, It works fine. But, what I'm looking for is scrolling to specific text (using window.find()) that may be  changed from run to run. Because of that scrolling into constant element not cover my case.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: Hi Robert, 
I've seen answers similar to this one. I tried to do the scrolling using $('#iframe_element').contents().find('#container_element').scrollTop($('#other_element').offset().top()) (other_element is normal html element inside container_element, not a selection) and it works (also using animation). 
$('#iframe_element').contents().find('#container_element').scrollTop(500) also works.

It seems to me that the problem is with the text selection. When I debug this in chrome console, I can see that the selection sets to 0 for some reason.

Thanks.